# What is the fastest way to convert a string into an array of 1 item

Tags: c#

Let's say I would like something like this:

```
string s = "hello";
string[] array = s.ToStringArray()
```

and `array[0]` (the only element) holds the value >> "hello"

Comment: Fastest for you or for the computer? If it's for the computer please tell us why you have to optimize it :).

Comment: Why would you create from a stirng a single array? Where is the point?

Comment: Cause i need to pass it to a method that expects an array and i often get a single string variable.

Answer (score 7):

```
string[] array= new string[] { s };
```

Comment: hehe ..i know that. I meant if there is a method or something out there, else i will have to write an extension for it

Comment: @MitjaBonca You could have some other method that takes an array, even though it's a valid operation to perform on a one-item array.  I.e. Look at string.split.

Answer (score 3):

simplest way:

```
string[] array = { s };
```

also, you may use the `var` keyword:

```
var array = new string[] { s };
```

Comment: @the_ajp why don't you try it and see?

Comment: @phoog I am starting vs now but it takes a while :)

Comment: @the_ajp http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664573(v=vs.71).aspx and also http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288453(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: @IntermediateHacker  Cool site, I've never seen that before

Comment: And this is how we learn :). It's a bit of a dent in my ego though that I didn't know about it.

Answer (score 2):

In `c#` types are infered by the compiler.

```
var s = "hello";
var array = new [] { s };
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want function-way to do that, my best guess would be this:

```
string a = "abcd";
var b = a.Split("".ToCharArray());
```

But as everyone else said - there is no build-in function to cast a string to one-item array.

**EDIT**:
Just noticed that you need to pass array to method. In that case, the best solution would be to have method overload, that accepts string parameter and then casts it to array + executes required method like this:

```
public WhateverMethodType Method(string param){
    return Method(new string[] { param });
}

public WhateverMethodType Method (string[] param){
    // <...>
}
```

Hope that helped you.